# Definition of $\sin$ function on vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we define $\sin$ function on any vector space?
I used the logic for $\sin$ define on complex numbers
$\sin(x+iy)$ but how to generalize it?

Comment: You probably cannot define a sine function on any ol' vector space, but it is likely that you can extend the definition to a reasonable class of fields (or algebras) that possess a complete metric structure.  The basic idea would be to work with power series.  For example, in $p$-adic land, we can define an exponential function via the formal power series $$ \exp_p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^j}{j!}, $$ where $j!$ is the usual factorial of a positive integer, which can then be embedded into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\mathbb{C}_p$ in the "obvious" manner.

Comment: Even so, the actual problem is quite a lot more delicate.  For example, the above power series does not converge on the entire space.  Indeed, it only converges on a disk near zero.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_exponential_function) gives a reasonable discussion of the problem.  I would expect that similar problems of convergence pop up in other settings.

Comment: Also, just for your information, I have voted to close this question, as I think that it lacks context.  You talk about generalizing the sine function to the complex numbers as $\sin(x+iy)$, but you don't explain how you have defined $\sin(x+iy)$.  Via a power series?  Via Euler's formula?  Something else?  What structures, exactly, are allowing this generalization.  I think that there is a really interesting question buried in here somewhere, but I am not sure that the question I'm thinking about is the question that you are trying to ask.

Comment: I imagine the answer to this depends on what triangles looks like in the space in question. Where the space isn't Euclidean then I'm pretty sure there would need to exist some map to a Euclidean space because Sine is inherently linked to the concepts of a straight line and a right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in the complex numbers we can multiply elements of our vector space. That, together with a notion of convergence, allows you to use the standard Taylor series for $\sin(z)$:
$$
   \sin(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \frac{z^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}.
$$
There are many other *algebras* (vector spaces with a natural multiplication) where we have a notion of convergence. These are the settings in which we expect to have a useful notion of $\sin(v)$.